# Not generating kernels that aren't there

Tags: grub2, kernel, dpkg

When I apt-get `dist-upgrade`, several 4.x kernels are reliably generated.

```
jeff@starshine:boot $ ls -lt
total 135676
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 68578468 Dec 23 09:27 initrd.img-5.0.0-37-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18585279 Dec 23 09:26 initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18585112 Dec 23 09:26 initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18585676 Dec 23 09:26 initrd.img-4.13.0-46-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Dec 12 12:56 grub
-rw------- 1 root root  8806136 Nov 13 22:36 vmlinuz-5.0.0-37-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   224480 Nov 13 20:35 config-5.0.0-37-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4440495 Nov 13 20:35 System.map-5.0.0-37-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Dec 17  2015 lost+found
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
jeff@starshine:boot $
```

Sometimes this causes the upgrade to run out of space.  The 4.x kernels appear no longer to exist on my machine:

```
jeff@starshine:boot $ dpkg --list | grep linux- | grep -Ev '^rc'
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu                 2.32-7ubuntu4                                       amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  linux-base                                4.5ubuntu1                                          all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                            1.178.7                                             all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                             5.0.0.37.39                                         amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-37                    5.0.0-37.40                                         all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic            5.0.0-37.40                                         amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                     5.0.0.37.39                                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic              5.0.0-37.40                                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                       5.0.0.37.39                                         amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                      5.0.0-37.40                                         amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic            5.0.0-37.40                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic      5.0.0-37.40                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-signed-generic                      5.0.0.37.39                                         amd64        Complete Signed Generic Linux kernel and headers (dummy transitional package)
ii  linux-sound-base                          1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                                all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  syslinux-common                           3:6.04~git20171011.af7e95c3+dfsg1-6                 all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-legacy                           2:3.63+dfsg-2ubuntu9                                amd64        Bootloader for Linux/i386 using MS-DOS floppies
jeff@starshine:boot $
```

Poking through grub configs, I've not found what is triggering these extra images to be created.  Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: `ls -al /var/lib/initramfs-tools/`  and `dpkg -l | egrep '^rc'`

Comment: I think you mean `egrep -v`. ;-)

Comment: Yes, initramfs-tools is the thing!  Thanks.  Do you know what manages this?  Is it perfectly safe just to rm the old entries?

Comment: Reading `man initramfs-tools`, it _looks_ like these files (a hash and a kernel name) are used as instructions to generate the images in /boot/.  The timestamps are identical to the second, and stat says those in /boot/ are always precisely an integral number of seconds, which suggests they are generated second with timestamp explicitly set.  So it seems worth the experiment.

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. If you don't have make an own config for apt/apt-get  for purging no longer needed or unavailable packages,  they will only be removed and  config files will remain  on your system.